# Ignoring Byte Order Mark or binary trash in front of JSON when using KSQLDB

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am using `io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter` as my value converter to generate the payload on a topic with the schema in the Schema Registry.

This leads to an error message when I try to create a ksqldb stream. The log entry reads:

> Invalid UTF-32 character 0x17a2249 (above 0x0010ffff) at char #1, byte #7)

Here are the first few hex values of the message:

[image]

Keep in mind that I have a bunch of messages, the screenshot and the error message are from two different offsets.

ksqldb seems to think this might be a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) given that the error message mentions `0x0010fff`.
JSON ([RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)) does not allow for a BOM and to me this just looks like obvious binary trash.
I think what the JsonSchemaConverter may be doing is prefacing the data with the schema version that was written into the Schema Registry, in this case 1

Is there a way to tell ksqldb to attempt to skip portions of a JSON message.

- until the structure starts to appear valid (first occurrence of pattern match `[\d[{"]`)?
- straight up skip 5 bytes?

Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong that has nothing to do with what I am seeing on a binary level?

EDIT:
It seems worth mentioning that I wanted a schema. I indicate that to ksqldb by using `VALUE_FORMAT='JSON_SR'` and that seems to work out and I am also using a JsonSchemaConverter so the schema is written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a JSON record. It's a Schema Registry Message including a JSON Schema along with a value. Magic Byte (0x0) + 4 byte int (Schema Id 1), then the remaining data.

You would need to have `value.converter.schemas.enabled=false` on your Connect properties to remove it.

Otherwise, if you want to keep a schema, AvroConverter would be better in terms of compatibility. Then you would automatically have a schema in KSQL rather than need to parse out individual fields.

Alternatively, I think `FORMAT="JSON"` is not what you want in KSQL because this assumes a record without a schema.

See note here : https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/serialization/#json

Comment: I do want a chema - I will try your avro suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I read the link - I have been trying everything you wrote to no avail except for 'io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter' which worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: JSON_SR did not solve it for me. I talked to a contact at confluent and he suspects that this may be related to the versions involved. So using avro to solve that was a good idea since that has been supported for a longer time now.

Comment: There is some documentation about the wire format described above, here:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format